# Why do I get different result when tracing into write() than other people?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, system-calls

I am doing some x86 exercises; my assignment has me stepping through the assembly code for the `write()` library call in a debugger until we reach a `SYSENTER` instruction, but I get different results from that of some of my classmates. What I saw leading up to `SYSENTER` was:

```
   │0xf7fdf421 <__kernel_vsyscall+1>        push   %edx                                                                                            
   │0xf7fdf422 <__kernel_vsyscall+2>        push   %ebp                                                                                            
   │0xf7fdf423 <__kernel_vsyscall+3>        mov    %esp,%ebp                                                                                       
   │0xf7fdf425 <__kernel_vsyscall+5>        sysenter
```

Is this what I should see? If so, why is it different from what some of my classmates saw?
Also are %edx and %ebp registers saved on the stack before executing the `sysenter` instruction? (Would it not seem so according to the answer I got or am I wrong?)

Here's my original instructions from my assignment:

The assembly code:

```
.file    "A3Program2.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string    "hello\n"
.LC1:
    .string    "xxxx\n"
    .text
.globl secondCall
    .type    secondCall, @function
secondCall:
    pushl    %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $40, %esp
    movl    $6, 8(%esp)
    movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp)
    movl    $1, (%esp)
    call    write
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    movl    $8, 8(%esp)
    movl    $.LC1, 4(%esp)
    movl    $1, (%esp)
    call    write
    addl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx
    leal    (%edx,%eax), %eax
    addl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
    leave
    ret
    .size    secondCall, .-secondCall
.globl firstCall
    .type    firstCall, @function
firstCall:
    pushl    %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $40, %esp
    movl    $2, 4(%esp)
    movl    $4, (%esp)
    call    secondCall
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
    leave
    ret
    .size    firstCall, .-firstCall
.globl main
    .type    main, @function
main:
    pushl    %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    call    firstCall
    movl    %eax, 12(%esp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .size    main, .-main
    .ident    "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

**The following instructions are for Linux:**

Find the line number of the second call to write, “call write”, in the secondCall
function. Set a break point at this line. Which is 22 according to me.

Set a break point at this line.

```
 break 22
```

Run the program inside the debugger.

```
 run
```

The program will stop at the break point you set.
Step into the code which does not have the debugging information.

```
  si
```

You will see “[ No Source Available ]” in the source layout. So you need to view 
the disassembled instructions.

```
 layout asm
```

Repeatedly step into (si and then  return/enter will execute the  si command 
repeatedly) until you see “sysenter” appear in the asm layout section of the screen.
I am trying to copy the instructions (including their addresses) from the top of the asm layout section, down to and including the sysenter instruction.

Hint: You can change the focus of the keyboard to the command area by typing Ctrl-x o. This 
      way the arrow keys can be used to bring back earlier commands (it just saves some 
      typing).

Comment: ... what's your question, exactly?

Comment: I want to know if the answer I got is correct....I mentioned that in the question itself...

Comment: Please do not edit out the content of your question when you get the answer. If the answer can be found below, accept it; otherwise write the answer you found and accept your own answer. This will help future searchers with the same question.

Comment: Your answer did not answer my question. I got help from my group members.

Comment: so post your answer so others can benefit. Or leave the question alone, in hopes that someone will come along and post an answer that will be helpful for others. Don't just erase all the context. I spent quite some time on my answer, and I'd like to see it be helpful for someone else, even if you don't care for the answer.

Comment: please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36110/what-is-the-protocol-when-deleting-your-own-question

Comment: also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96670/deleting-my-own-question

Comment: If you really want your question deleted, please flag it for moderator attention, and give a good reason in the description.

Comment: I won't revert this any more myself. But I've reported this to the moderators. You've come here asking for advice, even if you think you don't want it anymore it's the least you can do to leave this question in a form where it'll help others. By all means, add something on the bottom saying "I don't care anymore", but asking for an answer, rejecting it without even saying why, and then making the question (and answer!) useless to others is just plain _rude_.

Comment: Dude I have voted you up for the answer. I have also given a reason at the bottom why it was not the answer I was looking for. What else do you want? I dont want to disclose my code anymore.

Comment: it's not about upvotes. It's about leaving something behind that will help others in the future. I have 41.8k rep, I don't really care about one upvote here or there. What I care is that the time I spent researching and answering your question doesn't get flushed down the toilet because you wanted a yes-or-no answer to reassure you rather than any real insight into what's going on. That's why I ask that you leave your question in a form that others can benefit from, even if you decide you don't like the answer yourself.

Comment: also, to any mods reading this: I'd be happy to reword the content of the question (the original was a bit long-winded) to make it easier to reference, but only once I know it won't be immediately reverted by the OP

Comment: Also, please note, Jay, that this is not just my opinion. This is SO policy: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108617/user-deleting-code-after-question-has-been-answered

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BZkFNkc2 proposed summarization of the original question content; I'll edit this in once we hear from a mod, or if we don't, I will apply this edit tomorrow.

Comment: LOL! you even reworded what I had posted initially. All good. Let the mod look.

Comment: Jay you've totally embarrassed yourself here. You ask a question. You get a good answer (better than the question deserved actually, in my opinion). You whine that the question isn't exactly what you want. You show absolutely no gratitude. You do your best to make sure nobody will get any benefit from the answer in future. You're unbelievable, and not in a good way.

Comment: Bill you should say that to my face when I come down to wellington...gotta come down there to view a car. Come have a talk then..haha skeed!

Comment: What is going on in here?

Answer (score 10):

You are tracing into what is called the ['virtual dynamic shared object' (VDSO)](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/) - the contents of which are an *implementation detail* of the linux kernel. There are a number of conditions that can cause the contents of the VDSO to change; as such *there is no single correct answer here*.

In particular, on 32-bit x86 systems, there are at least three different mechanisms that can be used to make a system call:

- `INT $0x80`
- `SYSCALL` (recent AMD CPUs)
- `SYSENTER` (recent Intel CPUs)

You'll note that only `INT $0x80` works on all CPUs (indeed, the kernel makes it available for legacy applications even when more modern alternatives are also available); however, it's also slow. The kernel will probe for which are supported at boot time, and select a version of the VDSO that uses the most efficient mechanism available.

As such, depending on your CPU model, you may see different code in the VDSO - in particular, if you have an AMD CPU, you're likely to see the `SYSCALL` path, and if you have a really old CPU you might even see the `INT $0x80` path. If you're curious about the others, here's the source code:

- [`INT $0x80` method](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.4/arch/x86/vdso/vdso32/int80.S)
- [`SYSCALL` method](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.4/arch/x86/vdso/vdso32/syscall.S)
- [`SYSENTER` method](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.4/arch/x86/vdso/vdso32/sysenter.S) - read the comments for why `%ecx`, `%edx`, and `%ebp` are pushed

Most likely, the other folks in your lab who got a different result had an AMD CPU and were looking at the `SYSCALL` path (or they had an antique PC, and were looking at the `INT $0x80` path).

Note also that in a 64-bit process, `SYSCALL` will be used directly, without going through the VDSO at all.

Comment: I am not really lookin for this sort of answer. I just want to know if the answer I got is correct and if it is not then how to fix it.

Comment: @Jay, there is no one 'correct answer' here. The contents of the VDSO are an implementation detail. The kernel people can change it at any time - and, as I said, it does indeed vary. If all you're interested in is whether this is 'correct', I think you have misunderstood the aim of your exercise - isn't it to understand the behavior you see?

Comment: Also note that INT $0x80 is always available even if the kernel has selected another method in the VDSO. This is not an accident.

Comment: Yes, some old programs hardcoded INT $0x80, and I think certain parts of libc still open-code it.

Comment: @Jay, wow, bdonlan gives one of the _best_ write-ups of this functionality I've ever seen -- and incidentally, provides you with reasons why you and your fellow tutorialists got different answers -- and you're _unhappy_??

Comment: The write up is fine. I have it in my notes. Thanks for th writeup though.

Comment: @bdonlan: Your last remark is wrong. `sysenter` is *never* used on 64-bit. The 64-bit ISA was designed by AMD and has `syscall`, not `sysenter`.

Comment: @R..Oops, indeed. Fixed. :)